# Однократное считывание из файла значения

Tags: java

Необходимо что бы при многократном обращении к методу `getProperty` он не считывал постоянно файл по ключ-значение, а сделал это один раз и дальше работал с этим значением из памяти.

```
public class PropertiesLoaderImpl implements PropertiesLoader {

    public static Properties properties;

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        properties = new Properties();
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties");
            properties.load(file);
            return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Насколько правильно это решение, будет ли он постоянно читать файл при каждом обращении или один раз?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данной реализации значение считывается из файла при каждом вызове метода.

Для однократного чтения файла, можно, например, использовать проверку на `null` для поля `properties` (*lazy initialization*):

```
public class PropertiesLoaderImpl implements PropertiesLoader {
    public static Properties properties;

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties")) {
                properties.load(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

или статический блок инициализации:

```
public class PropertiesLoaderImpl implements PropertiesLoader {
    public static Properties properties;

    static {
        properties = new Properties();
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties")) {
            properties.load(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        return properties.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```